# Unable to run emulator on Android Studio || Windows 10

Tags: android, qt, android-studio, android-emulator, qtplugin

I have got really frustrated with this issue for the past 24 hours. I downloaded and installed Android Studio 3.2.1 on my E: . I have my Android SDK path set to C:\Users\anant\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk . However, when I try to run the emulator Nexus 5 API 27, I receive the error attached as a screenshot. It is related to some plugin "qt". Strangely, the path mentioned in the error popup is an empty folder. However, that folder structure does show up in Android Studio I try to change the SDK path. I did not find any QT folder inside the SDK path either. Interestingly, the folder in which the "plugins" are expected to be found seems "disabled" on the SDK path window and it is indeed empty. I am attaching the exact contents of the folder after searching it in the File explorer.

[image: Error message]

[image: Most folders hidden]

[image: File explorer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it happened me once. You can fix it installing the package **Android Emulator** from the SDK Manager:

Tools>Android>SDK Manager

1. Open the "SDK Tools" tab
2. Enable Android Emulator
3. Finally, press the "Apply" button.

I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked for me too. I uninstalled Emulator, restarted system, resintalled emulator and now it opens.